# matching regex for custom params in URI

Tags: javascript, python, html, regex, web

I am building a web framework and REGEX is really hostile today.
I do not like the django way of formatting custom params with angle brackets

```
url/<param>/... or
<str:token>/
```

I would prefer the way js and other programs handle this

```
name/:token/:another_param
```

After trying for 45 minutes I am giving up. I would like to allow only characters like `a-zA-Z0-9_:/`. The main issue here is that I do not want to allow recursive colons like this

```
:::id
```

These are strings I would like to match

```
empty string (although I could check prior matching)
/
:id
/:id
/:id/
person/:name/:id/:token_person2/image
person////
////
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: Can you add more details like an example of a URL containing an id and a token and the expected result

Comment: it does not matter. These are the strings I would like to match.

Comment: Is there anything else that you **don't** want to match?

Comment: Do you mean like this? `^(?![\/\w:]*::)[\/\w:]*$` https://regex101.com/r/oH19sy/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird that's great!! However this still matches a string like `person/:/name`. I do not want to allow nothing after the colon. Maybe I could still handle it, but theoretically it should be considered as a mistake made by the dev

Comment: You could extend it like `^(?![\/\w:]*:[:/])[\/\w:]*$` https://regex101.com/r/gyGJqx/1

Comment: Thank you very much fourth bird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to match `::` and apparently also not `:/`

What you can do is use a single negative lookahead to assert that those 2 strings do not occur.

```
^(?![/\w:]*:[:/])[/\w:]*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?![/\w:]*:[:/])` Negative lookahead, assert not `::` or `:/` to the right
- `[/\w:]*` Optionally repeat matching one of `/`, `\w` (word character) or `:`
- `$` End of string

```js
const regex = /^(?![/\w:]*:[:/])[/\w:]*$/;
[
  "",
  "/",
  ":id",
  "/:id",
  "/:id/",
  "person/:name/:id/:token_person2/image",
  "person////",
  "////",
  ":::id",
  "person/:/name",
].forEach(s =>
  console.log((regex.test(s) ? "" : "No ") + `Match --> '${s}'`)
)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BaEXo9/1)